# Database is updating correctly, but getting errors

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

My current code is giving me the following errors, the first when I add a record and the second when I delete or update a record. The database still updates correctly in these instances

To Further explain, I can add something like XXX, which wasn't in the database in the beginning, I got error #1, even though the database updated. When I delete that entry, the database updates, and I get error #2. If I go back and insert XXX again, the database updates, and I get error #1 again.

EDIT#2, I did notice in the datbase that the `UNIQUE KEY`  column is skipping numbers, so I can add VVV, error 1 occurs, it gets the `UNIQUE KEY` of 136. Then add VUV, get error #1 and the `UNIQUE KEY` is 138

Violation of `UNIQUE KEY` constraint `AK_DimCurrency_CurrencyAlternateKey`. Cannot insert duplicate key in object `dbo.DimCurrency`. The duplicate key value is (XXX). The statement has been terminated.

The `IListSource` does not contain any data sources.

```
public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    SqlConnection vid = new SqlConnection("Data Source=(LocalDB)\\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=\\AdventureWorksDW_Data.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30");
    static DataTable dtDataForGrid = new DataTable();

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void ButtonSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)//on button click the database connection is opened and the query is executed if possible, if not error will display on label 1
    {
        LabelError.Text = "";

        try
        {
            string str = TextBox1.Text;
            SqlCommand xp = new SqlCommand(str, vid);

            vid.Open();
            xp.ExecuteNonQuery();

            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
            da.SelectCommand = xp;
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds);
            GridView1.DataSource = ds;
            GridView1.DataBind();
            vid.Close();
        }

        catch (Exception c)
        {
            LabelError.Text = (c.Message);
        }
    }

    protected void ButtonReset_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)//resets the page, if error, it will display at label 1
    {
        try
        {
            Response.Redirect("~/Default.aspx");
        }
        catch (Exception c)
        {
            LabelError.Text = (c.Message);
        }
    }

    protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)//drop down list that adds text depending on choice to reduce redundant typing in multiple executions
    {
        if (DropDownList1.SelectedIndex == 1)
        {
            TextBox2.Text = "INSERT INTO";
            TextBox3.Text = " VALUES";
            TextBox4.Text = "";
            TextBox4.Enabled = false;
        }
        if (DropDownList1.SelectedIndex == 2)
        {
            TextBox2.Text = "UPDATE";
            TextBox3.Text = " SET";
            TextBox4.Text = " WHERE";
            TextBox4.Enabled = true;
        }
        if (DropDownList1.SelectedIndex == 3)
        {
            TextBox2.Text = "DELETE FROM";
            TextBox3.Text = " WHERE";
            TextBox4.Text = "";
            TextBox4.Enabled = false;
        }
    }

    protected void ButtonChange_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)//executes the operation from textbox2, and 3.
    {
        LabelError2.Text = "";//resets the label to nothing before changing the text again if needed below
        LabelFullOperation.Text = "";//resets the label to nothing before changing the text again if needed below

        if (TextBox4.Text == null)//sets the label6 text to textbox 2 and 3, unless 4 has text, in which case 2, 3, and 4 will be used
        {
            LabelFullOperation.Text = TextBox2.Text + TextBox3.Text;
        }
        else
        {
            LabelFullOperation.Text = TextBox2.Text + TextBox3.Text + TextBox4.Text;
        }
        try
        {
            string str = TextBox2.Text + TextBox3.Text + TextBox4.Text;//gets the text from textboxes 2, 3, adn 4, if any
            SqlCommand xp = new SqlCommand(str, vid);

            vid.Open();
            xp.ExecuteNonQuery();

            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
            da.SelectCommand = xp;
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds);
            GridView1.DataSource = ds;
            GridView1.DataBind();
            vid.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception c)
        {
            LabelError2.Text = (c.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: If I were a betting man, I'd say the issue is that you can perform an `INSERT` on a row that already exists in the database. You shouldn't be able to `INSERT` into a row that already exists in the database (i.e. has a key).

Comment: I can enter a test of XXX, which isn't in the database, but I still get this error. I received this error on the very first entry after verifying that the actual record didn't exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your are executing your SQL twice.  The first time it is executed is during the call to

```
xp.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

This works, but then the SQL is executed the 2nd time when you call

```
da.Fill(ds);
```

which throws the errors you are seeing.

Since you want a DataSet in the end, try removing the `xp.ExecuteNonQuery();` line.

Comment: Removing that line did fix the number jumping and error #1. Error #2 is still happening with any operations other than a basic search.

Comment: @JLM, please post the exception name and details you get for error #2.

Comment: The IListSource does not contain any data sources. I just figured it out. It had to do with the datasource code

Comment: Oh, that's by design. `UPDATE` and `DELETE` commands don't return the records that they changed.  `SELECT` is the only command that will load data in your dataset and let you bind it to the grid view.  That's why the property is called `SelectCommand` on the data adapter.

Answer (score 0):

You may be giving it table entries with the same key again.
See every time you execute your code, the values will get inserted into the table. So if you are executing it again and giving it the same value each time for the primary key, it will give an error.

So you can either delete the old record if it is redundant, or you can test your program with a different primary key.

Comment: I can add a test of XXX, the database updates with that entry, and I get the error. I delete the entry, the database updates and I get the ILIST error, and when I insert XXX again I get the first error again.

Comment: If you have a check for XXX then in an empty table, the ILIST error will come.